# Loading a million record in MongoDB as fast as possible

Tags: node.js, linux, mongodb, performance

I have a big database with more than 30 million records, How can I know where is the bottleneck in my server and why my query takes time.

My Database is well indexed and when I select records not all the records examined.

I know loading a million record is unusual thing, but in case I want to load these records as fast as possible, how to know why the query takes time? is there's any monitoring tools?

In other words, if somebody is asking: I have a good CPU and SSD why this query takes so long, what should the answer be?

in my opinion I think this related to SSD speed and the number of cores used to find the records, and NodeJS uses only one core. is that right?

Query Example:

```
db.bios.find( { birth: { $gt: new Date('2019-01-01'), $lt: new Date('2000-01-01') } } )
```

`birth` here is unique indexed in my case.

Comment: Can you share the query you are using to load your million records?

Comment: As written, I think the question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. It is lacking too many details, and does not have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Folks need more than "I have a good CPU and SSD...". You should probably move this question to [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/). They may be able to help you analyze your system and gather statistics.

Comment: @jww,  I'm just giving an example, I meant to say, is it related to CPU or SSD, I'm not talking about a specific computer spec, it's just a general question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a good CPU and SSD why this query takes so long, what should the answer be?

You also need to consider if you have enough RAM for your indexes to fit into. After that you need to do some query optimization

> how to know why the query takes time? is there's any monitoring tools?

Look into [profiling](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) your database. This will record slow queries, and you can see which indexes were chosen and how long each query took.

This should give you a good insight into the database performance. There are some tools you can use to visualize this data (here is a [blog post](http://tech.rhealitycheck.com/visualizing-mongodb-profiling-data-using-logstash-and-kibana/) detailing using Logstash and Kibana for this).

> NodeJS uses only one core. is that right?

NodeJS mostly runs in a single thread, but you can spawn more threads via [cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) or [worker](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html). 
But the database runs in it's own process on multiple threads and should be running on a separate server than your Node application.

#### Fast Query for loading many documents

There will be a sweet spot in how many documents to load per Database request. It will depend on the size of your documents, and the query.

From the [mongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#operations):

> **Sort Operations**
>
> If MongoDB cannot use an index to get documents in the requested sort order, the combined size of all documents in the sort operation, plus a small overhead, must be less than 32 megabytes.

Say for example this works out to around 500 documents.

Add a sort order to be in incrementing order on the `birth` field. Make sure to index your sort field (`birth`), then fetch the first 500 documents using `limit`. Take the last document returned, and use it's value for `birth` to limit your next query. Then keep on looping until you found all documents.

First query would be

```
db.bios.find( { birth: { $gt: new Date('2019-01-01'), $lt: new Date('2000-01-01') } } )
```

If last object returned had `birth` of `'2019-01-05'`

Second query would be

```
db.bios.find( { birth: { $gt: new Date('2019-01-05'), $lt: new Date('2000-01-01') } }
```

and so on.

If you use [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/), I've written a small [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-fast-pagination) to make this operation easier (but it's without tests as it was only for a personal project initially)

---

### Update: Hardware Requirements

There is no easy way to find  out what will bottle neck your MongoDB instance as it depends on your usage
 - Lots of indexes and compound indexes
 - Smaller documents or larger documents
 - Write once read often, or update often (Do your documents grow in size?)
 - Complex aggregations

The best way to test this is via a scaled test, as MongoDB should scale linearly. If you anticipate a 1TB collection, try creating an example collection of 1GB size with the same indexes and schema. Run it on a cheap, weak server. Run your queries against it and look at resource usage (CPU, RAM, DISK I/O, network)

There are some good docs and blog posts on this subject you can look into:

- [Capacity Planning](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/capacity-planning-and-hardware-provisioning-mongodb-ten-minutes)
- [Hardware Considerations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/#hardware-considerations)
- [Diagnostics](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/faq/diagnostics/#faq-memory)

Schema

You should also look at [redesigning your schema](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1) if you need to load that much data very quickly and often.

I doubt you are displaying 1 million lines of data in a UI. If you are loading data to process it, maybe save the processed data as a new collection (eg. for graphs). If you need to search through it, use a query / filter. If a full text search is needed across multiple fields, consolidate it to a single field. Or consider using a DB optimized for such operations (eg. Casandra)

Comment: Thanks for your amazing answer, I still don't know, what hardware to upgrade in case I need to get a better performance for my mongoDB server. for example, how do I know if the CPU is good but the problem with RAM? Loading a million records takes 17 second, how to load that within 1 second? multiple SSD disk - RAID 0 maybe?

Comment: @Jennifer I've added an update for your comment to my answer